# Show JSON data in a TableView with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to display some data I take from a data base into a `TableView` but the data is not shown in the `TableView`. The data I receive is formatted in JSON.

This is the data I receive form the data base and what I want to print in the `TableView`is just David:

```
{"name":"David"}
```

This is the code to get the data from de data base:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/Patients.php")!)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, downloadError in

        if let error = downloadError {
            print("Could not complete the request \(error)")
        }
        else {

            do {
                self.json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            } catch {
                fatalError()
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                if let parseJSON = self.json{

                    let name = parseJSON["name"] as! String

                    self.arrayData.append(name)

                    print("Data1:\(self.arrayData)")
                }

            })
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

arrayData is an `array` where I put the data I receive from the data base and it is declared like this:

```
var arrayData: [String] = []
```

The code

```
print("Data1:\(self.arrayData)")
```

show in the console this `Data1:["David"]`, so I get the data correctly.

Then I implement the methods to print in the ´TableView´, the `numberOfSectionsInTableView`method, the `numberOfRowsInSection` method and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method but the data is not printed in the `TableView`.

I think the problem is that the `TableView`is drawn before I put the data in the `array` so it prints nothing because the array is empty, and I don´t know how to fix it.

Anyone knows what is my problem?

Comment: Have you tried to call `tableView.reloadData()` after changing contents of the array?

Comment: That solved my problem! Thank you Sebastian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you're right.

> session.dataTaskWithRequest

is async. Data is not returned immediately, it have delay. 
You must to reload tableview after recieved data:

```
self.arrayData.append(name)
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

Usually i will use block:

```
func getData(handleComplete:((arr:NSMutableArray)->())){
    let aray = NSMutableArray()
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/Patients.php")!)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, downloadError in

        if let error = downloadError {
            print("Could not complete the request \(error)")
        }
        else {

            do {
                self.json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            } catch {
                fatalError()
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                if let parseJSON = self.json{

                    let name = parseJSON["name"] as! String

                    aray.append(name)

                    print("Data1:\(self.arrayData)")
                }
                handleComplete(aray)

            })
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    arrayData
}
```

and in viewdidload i will call:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getData { (arr) -> () in
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

it 's better